# Freeing memory of an array of struct variables

Tags: c

```
 typedef struct _TRANSITION TRANSITION;

typedef struct {
    char name[4];
    bool is_initial;
    bool is_final;
    TRANSITION *transitions;
    int number_transitions;
} STATE;

struct _TRANSITION {
    char c;
    STATE *dest;
};

 void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state) {
        if (pp_state != NULL && *pp_state != NULL) {
            free((*pp_state)->transitions);
            (*pp_state)->transitions = NULL;
        }
        free(*pp_state);
        *pp_state = NULL;
  }
```

What I want to do is to delete a `STATE`. So I need to free all the `TRANSITION` my state has. Here you can see the functions that create these structs:

```
STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final) {
    STATE *state = (STATE *) malloc(sizeof(STATE));
    if (state != NULL) {
        strcpy(state->name, name);
        state->is_initial = is_initial;
        state->is_final = is_final;
        state->transitions = NULL;
        state->number_transitions = 0;
    }
    return state;
}

void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest) {
    if (source != NULL && dest != NULL) {
        TRANSITION *transitions = source->transitions;
        TRANSITION *trans = source->transitions;
        int i;
        if (transitions != NULL) {
            transitions = (TRANSITION *) realloc(transitions, sizeof(TRANSITION) * ((source->number_transitions) + 1));           
        } else {
            transitions = (TRANSITION *) malloc(sizeof(TRANSITION));
        }
        trans = (transitions + source->number_transitions);
        trans->c = sign;
        trans->dest = dest;
        (source->number_transitions)++;
        source->transitions = transitions;
    }
}
```

However, as I tested my function in the main method with this:

```
STATE *first = create_state("S'0", true, false);
STATE *second = create_state("S'1", false, false);
printf("%s: Initial: %d, Final: %d\n", first->name, first->is_initial, first->is_final);
add_transition(first, 'A', second);
add_transition(first, 'B', second);
add_transition(first, 'C', second);
TRANSITION *transition = first->transitions;
printf("%c", transition[0].c); // Output: A
printf("%c", transition[1].c); // Output: B
printf("%c\n", transition[2].c); // Output: C

destroy_state(&first);

printf("%c", transition[0].c); // Output: 
printf("%c", transition[1].c); // Output: B
printf("%c", transition[2].c); // Output: C
```

It seems like that I just deleted the first `TRANSITION` (Output commented on the `printf()` functions).

Obviously I did something wrong.
My first solution to this problem was that I have to iterate over the transitions. But since I just allocate space for one array of `TRANSITION`s, I don't see that working (and as I expected, it didn't work).

What is my mistake?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbol names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the "implementation" (i.e. the compiler and the standard library).

Comment: And all-uppercase names should only be used for enum-constants and macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
TRANSITION *transition = first->transitions;
```

you save the pointer to the memory. Then you free the memory, but that doesn't change the pointer variable `transition` you defined and initialized above. So when you dereference `transition` you access memory that is not allocated and you have *undefined behavior*.

You have to remember that just like allocating memory doesn't initialize the contents of the allocated memory, freeing memory doesn't do anything to the contents of the memory either. So when accessing it after freeing it, parts of it may still keep its old contents.

Comment: But did I not set it to `NULL` in the `destroy_state` function? Isn't that the point why we have to set the variable `NULL` so that behavior doesn't accur?

Comment: @DennisvonEich No you set `first->transitions` to `NULL`, any other variable is separate. For example if you have e.g. `int a = 5, b; b = a; a = 0;` you would not expect the variable `b` to change when you modify the variable `a`? It's the same thing here, you modify one variable, and it has no connection to any other variables, it just happens that you have two different variables with the same value.

Comment: I see. So I can fix this problem by just setting the variable like this `transition = first->transitions;` again so it is updated. Right? I mean before I access it again after I called the method that frees the memory.

Comment: @DennisvonEich Not really, because `first` doesn't point to allocated memory, so using that pointer will also lead to undefined behavior. You simply have to keep track of all your pointers, and once you have called `free` on one of them don't touch them (other than to reassign to some other valid memory).

Comment: How does `first`not point on allocated memory? `create_state` is allocating memory for the state.

Comment: @DennisvonEich I mean after you call `destroy_state`, `first` no longer points to allocated memory.